# Blacklist word in RegExp statement

Tags: regex, passwords

I would like to create a ReExp expression that would match criterias:

- All non-whitespace characters are allowed.
- Minimum length 8 characters.
- Maximum length not limited.
- There should be at least 1 lowercase, 1 uppercase letter and 1 digit.
- Words 'pass' and 'password' are prohibited.

Without last rule, it will look like this:

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?\d)[\S]{8,}$
```

How would I add black-listed words in here?

Comment: What language is this in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a negative lookahead assertion.

```
^(?!pass(?:word)?$)(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?\d)\S{8,}$
```

Comment: Thank you for help, this almost solves the problem. However something like "123_ABC_pass_foo" still passes regex. Let say I would like to completely exclude any possible appearance of some keywords (at any place of the string). How would I do this?

Comment: then `^(?!.*?pass(?:word)?)(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?\d)\S{8,}$`